# HuggingFace/HfAgent AttributeError: module transformers.tools has no attribute DocumentQuestionAnsweringTool

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface

When trying to create an HfAgent, you get the error

`AttributeError: module transformers.tools has no attribute DocumentQuestionAnsweringTool`

from your .run request

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you don't have Pytorch installed in your or Tensorflow installed in your environment. I fixed this by doing `pip install transformers[torch]`

See install instructions - https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/installation